# ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: '2015-01-01'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to convert values to axis units. I checked codes with similar problems but none addressed this specific challenge. As can be seen in the image below, expected plot (A) was supposed to show month (Jan, Feb etc.) on the x-axis, but it was showing dates (2015-01 etc) in plot (B).

[image]

Below is the source code, kindly assist. Thanks.

```
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 18

plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
plt.plot(df.air_temperature,label="Air temperature at Frankfurt Int. Airport in 2015")
plt.xlim(("2015-01-01","2015-12-31"))
plt.xticks(["2015-{:02d}-15".format(x) for x in range(1,13,1)],["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"])
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel("Temperature (°C)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, could you provide a sample of your data in `df`?

Comment: Yes, I can. Here is the link to the CSV data: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eD2UHdM8leY66mdFKhJ2BFz1XIaYWFO1/view?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wise way to draw the plot with datetime is to use `datetime` format in place of `str`; so, first of all, you should do this conversion:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/frankfurt_weather.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Then you can set up the plot as you please, preferably following [Object Oriented Interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/):

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,5))

ax.plot(df['time'], df['air_temperature'], label = 'Air temperature at Frankfurt Int. Airport in 2015')

ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')

plt.show()
```

Then you can customize:

- x ticks' labels format and position with [**`matplotlib.dates`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html):

  ```
  ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MonthLocator(interval = 1))
  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%b'))
  ```
- x axis limits:

  ```
  ax.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d'),
               pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31', format = '%Y-%m-%d')])
  ```
- capital first letter of x ticks' labels for months' names

  ```
  fig.canvas.draw()
  ax.set_xticklabels([month.get_text().title() for month in ax.get_xticklabels()])
  ```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md


df = pd.read_csv(r'data/frankfurt_weather.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')


plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,5))

ax.plot(df['time'], df['air_temperature'], label = 'Air temperature at Frankfurt Int. Airport in 2015')

ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MonthLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%b'))

ax.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31', format = '%Y-%m-%d')])

fig.canvas.draw()
ax.set_xticklabels([month.get_text().title() for month in ax.get_xticklabels()])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, the answer was perfect and very useful. I tried scoring you but I keep getting a message that my reputation has to be up to 15 before I can score you. I  appreciate your prompt and accurate response, thanks.

Comment: @Zephre, any chance you would like to take a look at the problem I encountered while trying to plot multiple axes on a figure using matplotlib. Here is the link on StackOverflow: (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71199328/18075079) Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer. Feel free to upvote this and/or that answer, if you find them useful :-)

Comment: Hi! I am trying to format the dates for **hours** using the codes below but I keep getting a syntax error. Please, your view on what you think I might be doing wrong?  `ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1)           
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H')) ` .  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: this is the last part of the code for context `ax1.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2011.08.05', format = '%Y.%m.%d'), pd.to_datetime('2022.01.28', format = '%Y.%m.%d')])`

Comment: I just tried voting again, I got a message that says `You can't vote for your own post`. Please check again, every single answer you preferred that solved my issues were fully accepted and an appreciation message was written. Please check again.

Comment: You are probably getting a `SyntaxError` because there is a typo in the code you wrote: in `ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1)` you opened two `(` but closed only one `)`. The correct syntax should be `ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1))`

Comment: After fixing the typo as you rightly pointed out, no plot was outputted, Rather, I am getting this message: `Locator attempting to generate 91897 ticks ([15191.0, ..., 19020.0]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000).` Permit me to share the codes in bits for context, please. Thanks

Comment: `plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18`
`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))`
`ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)`      
`ax2 = ax1.twinx()`
`ax1.plot(df.OPEN, label = 'open')`
`ax1.plot(df.HIGH, label = 'high')`
`ax1.plot(df.LOW, label = 'low')`
`ax1.plot(df.CLOSE, label = 'close')`
`ax2.plot(df.VOLUME, label = 'volume')`
`ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1))`
`ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H'))`
`ax1.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2011.08.05', format = '%Y.%m.%d'), pd.to_datetime('2022.01.28', format = '%Y.%m.%d')])`

Comment: Dataframe:

     date               OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE VOLUME   
2011-08-05 19:00:00 1.04859 1.05224 1.04771 1.05010 5750

Comment: You should open an other answer in order to detail in a better way your issue. Report your code, what error you got, what you want to achieve

Comment: if you got some time, please take a look at this. Thanks.   **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756758/ticks-which-exceeds-locator-maxticks**

Answer (score 1):

(Just to clarify)

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: '2015-01-01'
```

was triggered because it was tried to put strings as limits.

First, they must be converted to something datetime-like. Better to `datetime64[us]` type (for Pandas DataFrame with datetime-like column [e.g. pandas.Timestamp] -- `df[DATE_COLUMN].astype('datetime64[us]')`) since it is the type to which matplotlib wants to conver input datetime-like objects.