# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dpi_scale_trans'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

Having checked through StackOverflow for a possible solution to the above error that I encountered, I found some solutions which were not able to solve this particular issue.
The following image shows the error encountered and the undesirable figure obtained while trying to plot multiple axes on a figure:

[image]

This is an image of the expected output: [image]

Also, the data I am working with can be found at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZxD3BwpJfEVMWPoxu-aom_wXawMfSywk/view?usp=sharing

Below is the set of codes that I have scripted, and I seem to have hit a roadblock. I would appreciate any help that will guide me to achieve the expected output @image2.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md

# Date already in DateTime index
dk1 = data.loc["1991":"2000"]      # selects all rows from 1991 - 2000
dk2 = data.loc["2001":"2010"]      # selects all rows from 2001 - 2010
dk3 = data.loc["2011":"2020"]      # selects all rows from 2011 - 2020

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))            # Create a figure for the plot

# Add three axes to the plots
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)                      
ax2 = plt.subplot(212) 
ax3 = plt.subplot(313) 

# Plot the data
ax1.plot(dk1.TX, label = 'Max temp')
ax2.plot(dk2.TX, label = 'Max temp')
ax3.plot(dk3.TX, label = 'Max temp')

# Set the title
ax1.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 1991~2000, tmax\n")
ax2.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 2001~2010, tmax\n")
ax3.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 2011~2020, tmax\n")

ax1.legend()                               # Plot the legend for first axes
ax2.legend()                               # Plot the legend for second axes
ax3.legend()                               # Plot the legend for third axes 

# Set the x- and y-axis label
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax1.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax2.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

ax3.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax3.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

# formatted X axis in Year
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

# Set the limits (range) of the X-Axis
ax1.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('1991 1 1', format = format),
             pd.to_datetime('2000 12 31', format = format)])

ax2.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2001 1 1', format = format),
             pd.to_datetime('2010 12 31', format = format)])

ax3.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2010 1 1', format = format),
             pd.to_datetime('2020 12 31', format = format)])

plt.show()
```

Comment: please replace google drive links with embedding of the image, I can assure you that a lot of people wouldn't be so keen to open some random link 

Comment: Please do not post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Noted! @Mr. T  Thanks

Comment: The nowadays recommended way to create the subplots is `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=3, figsize=(20,15))`. Note the plural in `subplots`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to the argument passed to [**`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html): since you want three plot on three different rows (same column), then you should use:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
```

---

In any case, your code need some changes in order to achieve the results you want.
First of all it is wise to convert `'Time'` column from `str` type to `datetime`:

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then, since you need to filter data based on year, you should create a column with the year:

```
data['year'] = data['time'].dt.year
```

At this point you can filter your data based on the `'year'` column:

```
dk1 = data[(data['year'] >= 1991) & (data['year'] <= 2000)]      # selects all rows from 1991 - 2000
dk2 = data[(data['year'] >= 2001) & (data['year'] <= 2010)]      # selects all rows from 2001 - 2010
dk3 = data[(data['year'] >= 2011) & (data['year'] <= 2020)]      # selects all rows from 2011 - 2020
```

As already mentioned, you should create the subplots in the proper way:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
```

Finally, pay attention to the `set_xlim` code: `format` is a special keyword in python:

```
ax1.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('1991 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2000 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])

ax2.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2001 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2010 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])

ax3.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2010 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2020 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])
```

### Complete code

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_csv(r'data/max_temp.csv')
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
data['year'] = data['time'].dt.year


# # Date already in DateTime index
dk1 = data[(data['year'] >= 1991) & (data['year'] <= 2000)]      # selects all rows from 1991 - 2000
dk2 = data[(data['year'] >= 2001) & (data['year'] <= 2010)]      # selects all rows from 2001 - 2010
dk3 = data[(data['year'] >= 2011) & (data['year'] <= 2020)]      # selects all rows from 2011 - 2020


plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))            # Create a figure for the plot

# Add three axes to the plots
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)

# Plot the data
ax1.plot(dk1.time, dk1.TX, label = 'Max temp')
ax2.plot(dk2.time, dk2.TX, label = 'Max temp')
ax3.plot(dk3.time, dk3.TX, label = 'Max temp')

# Set the title
ax1.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 1991~2000, tmax\n")
ax2.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 2001~2010, tmax\n")
ax3.set_title("Station: Ikeja, 2011~2020, tmax\n")

ax1.legend()                               # Plot the legend for first axes
ax2.legend()                               # Plot the legend for second axes
ax3.legend()                               # Plot the legend for third axes

# Set the x- and y-axis label
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax1.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax2.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

ax3.set_ylabel('Temperature (°C)\n')       # Set the Y-Axis label
ax3.set_xlabel('\nYear')                  # Set the X-Axis label

# formatted X axis in Year
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(month = 1, day = 1))     # formatted X axis in Year
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))  # set the date format to the year shortname

# Set the limits (range) of the X-Axis
ax1.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('1991 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2000 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])

ax2.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2001 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2010 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])

ax3.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2010 1 1', format = '%Y %m %d'),
             pd.to_datetime('2020 12 31', format = '%Y %m %d')])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your prompt response. You inspire me a lot.

Comment: @Zaphyr,  please how were you able to manipulate the subplot titles? Mine are overlapping? I tried using y=..., also tried adjusting the 'rcParams', but none worked. Kindly shed some light.

Comment: @Zaphyr, never mind. I was able to eventually solve the subplot overlapping by using the 'plt.tight_layout()' command.

Comment: @Deeone you can use the parameter `hspace` in `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 1)` to set the vertical space between subplots.

Comment: @Zephyr I believe I accepted your answer, and even the one you replied with `hspace`. Probably the question was moved. I am new around here, I am still trying to fully grasp how this community works. I will accept it once again. Like I told you before, you inspire me a lot and I do appreciate and acknowledge your solutions. Thanks once again